# Best practice with autoclose option on my SQL-Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I host thousand of databases on my SQL Server Instance and I would like to be advised on *autoclose* option.

I read that *autoclose* should be OFF, except in rare case, for example if you host thousand databases.

So if I set *autoclose* to ON, the database is shut down cleanly and its resources are freed after the last user exits. The database automatically reopens when a user tries to use the database again. Good for me, but my backup application doesn't work properly because can't access logs.

If I set *autoclose* to OFF, the database remains open after the last user exits. Until when SQL Server keep resources alive? Until next restart?

For me, best would be :

- *autoclose* to OFF
- SQL Server free resources every day (by script for example)

Do you have any idea / recommendation?

Comment: Any idea / recommendation ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not recommended to set AutoClose to ON or TRUE as it hampers the performance of following users/applications. Explained here..
http://sqlmag.com/blog/worst-practice-allowing-autoclose-sql-server-databases

Comment: Thanks @Rajesh Bhat! I already read this article that's why I wonder to change my *AutoClose* ON to OFF. But In my case I have around 1000 DB, and users access it only one day a  month. I would like to release resource during all rest of month. Do you know how to do that ?

Comment: If the database is used only once in a month you can restart the SQL server to release the resource. Also you can go thru' the below article if you already not gone thru'.              http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/115270/whats-a-good-way-to-get-sql-server-to-release-memory-to-the-operating-system-on